# Return to the application from google maps ios

Tags: ios

Sorry if this question has already been asked but i couldnt figure out how to search for it, since i dont know how its called.

Ive noticed that some applications offer the possibility to return to the application, after another application has been launched. Take the facebook application for example and its interaction with the facebook messenger, when you go to the timeline from the messenger a blue bar on top appears that allows the user to go back to the messenger application. I have also seen this in other applications that provide routing capabilities.

Does anyone know how to achieve this? I have the slight idea that it requires to register the application with back ground functionality or something along those lines.

What i want to do is, from an application that provides information about interesting places around the current user position, i offer the option to open google maps to take advantage of the routing information. But i want to show something on top so that the user can go back to my application.

Any help ill be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, using the callback URL the device can return to the application.

> If you'd like to specify a callback URL, you will need to use the
>   comgooglemaps-x-callback:// URL scheme. This scheme adheres to the
>   x-callback-url specification. When you call the Google Maps for iOS
>   app with this scheme, the app will display a button at the top of the
>   screen. Tapping this button will issue a callback to a URL that you've
>   specified.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/urlscheme?utm_source=welovemapsdevelopers&utm_campaign=GM-for-iOS-sdk-1-7